# How to style the same image with different dimensions using '<picture>'?

Tags: html, image, css

I have some images with different dimensions for the same image and I want to show them depending on screen size using `<picture>` , But I'm wondering how to style the selected image that fit the given size ?

I mean if I have this code :

```
<picture>
    <source media="(max-width: 300px)" srcset="image-300.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="image-600.jpg">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

and there is someone browsing my website from a "400px" screen then the "image-600.jpg" would be shown , and if someone else is browsing my website from different screen another different image (with different dimensions) , How to style this image that could be any of them ?

`picture{max-width:100%}` or `image{max-width:100%}` or what ?

also if he is using an old browser that doesn't support `<picture>` the `<img>` at the end of the element would be used , How to style it too ?

Comment: Just `picture img {max-width:100%}`, but didn't you try that already?

Comment: @MrLister , It's the 1st time I use it , So this way whatever the screen size the suitable image would be chosen and fill the whole width?

Comment: Yes, as long as the largest image is large enough.

Comment: So if my screen size is 500px and there is an image with ` <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="image-600.jpg">` , this image would be used filling the whole width?

Comment: What if the screen size is more than the max size "3000px"?